# Restcomm Visual Designer call flow - caller on hold plus callee finder with presence verification prompt

Tags: telephony, ivr, mobicents, restcomm

Is it currently possible to implement the following app logic with RVD:

1. Caller Alice rings a Restcomm app phone number
2. The app responds with prompt "Please hold on while you are being connected to Bob".
3. App puts Alice on hold.
4. App calls one or more alternative phone lines for Bob (mobile, office, tablet).
5. If any of Bob's devices answers, the app prompts to verify actual human presence: "Please press 1 to accept a call to your XYZ app number".
6. If Bob presses 1, the app connects Alice and Bob
7. If Bob does not press 1 , or if an answering machine such as Voice Mail picked up the call instead of Bob, the app will hang up that line and continue to ring the other lines.
8. After a total of 20 seconds of trying to reach Bob, he did not answer on any of the devices, the app takes Alice to a voice mail service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a call screening case. Your application can be implemented but it has some limitations:

- In order to implement the  to Bob you will need to nest "Number" nouns for each one of Bob's numbers. RVD does not support screening for "Client" or "SipURI" nouns.
- (7) is not supported. Restcomm cannot tell the difference between and an answering machine and a human. So if such a machine picks up the call first, Bob will not get it.

That being said, I would suggest an application with two modules:

Main module

You main module will contain a  that will call bob. Nest one  noun for each of Bob's numbers. Make sure that you set the "Before connect" in all of them to your screening module

Screening module

This module will get executed to ask Bob if he wants to receive the call from Alice. In this module you can inform Bob about the caller and ask him whether he wants to accept the call using a Collect/Menu. If Bob decides to reject the call bind your menu option with the 'Rejection Module' below. After the Collect you can shoud put a "Hungup" so that if Bob does not answer alice's all is dropped.

Comment: Thank you. This achieves most of what I'm looking for. Except it would be good to prevent a call going to voice mail inadvertently. Any ideas?